# Symfony 1.4 and editing/creating multiple models on one form?

Tags: php, symfony1

I have a module, called Users, that allows me create, well, users. However, i also have a model called Profiles. It's a different table than Users, but whenever i create a new user, i want to add a new Profile. Also, i want to add in the Profile table two fields, available in the User form. Do you guys have any idea of how to do that in Symfony?

Answer (score 0):

have a look at the [sfdoctrineapply](http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfDoctrineApplyPlugin) they are doing nearly exactly what you want to.

or in detail

```
#schema for the profile 
sfGuardUserProfile:
  tableName: sf_guard_user_profile
  columns:
    id:
      type: integer(4)
      primary: true
      autoincrement: true
    user_id:
      type: integer(4)
      notnull: true
    email:
      type: string(80)
    fullname:
      type: string(80)
    validate:
      type: string(17)
  # Don't forget this!
  relations:
    User:
      class: sfGuardUser
      foreign: id
      local: user_id
      type: one  
      onDelete: cascade    
      foreignType: one
      foreignAlias: Profile
```

and in your form where you create the user:

```
public function doSave($con = null)
  {
    $user = new sfGuardUser();
    $user->setUsername($this->getValue('username'));
    $user->setPassword($this->getValue('password'));
    // They must confirm their account first
    $user->setIsActive(false);
    $user->save();
    $this->userId = $user->getId();

    return parent::doSave($con);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all you have to create a custom form inside your forms folder. Inside this form add all the fields you need to create your user. Then you have to change your processForm method (or you can do it inside the method that shows the form as Flask suggests)

```
protected function processForm(sfWebRequest $request, sfForm $form){

$form->bind($request->getParameter('registration'));

if ($form->isValid())
{

  $user= new sfGuardUser();
  $user->setUsername($form->getValue('username'));
  $user->setPassword($form->getValue('password'));
  $user->setIsActive(true);
  $user->save();

  $profile= new sfGuardUserProfile();
  $profile->setUserId($user->getId());
  $profile->setName($form->getValue('nombre'));
  $profile->setSurname($form->getValue('apellidos'));
  $profile->setMail($form->getValue('username'));
  $profile->save();

  $this->redirect('@user_home');
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You must use embedded forms.
See this documentations:
http://symfony.com/blog/call-the-expert-customizing-sfdoctrineguardplugin
http://www.prettyscripts.com/framework/symfony/symfony-sfdoctrineguardplugin-and-customizing-user-profile